# Таблица html+css, текст наезжает на соседние ячейки

Tags: html, css, table

Стандартная таблица. Стили в шаблоне Wordpress, если нужно уточнить. Верстал не сам, не умею)
На узких экранах текст наезжает на соседние ячейки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стили такие:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 99%;
}
table thead tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table thead tr th {
    padding: 5px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table thead tr th:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}
table tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table tbody tr th, table tbody tr td {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно поправить?

Comment: А какой конкретно результат вы желаете видеть при столь маленькой ширине?

Comment: Тут особенно и не поправишь. Как вариант уменьшать размер шрифта. Но тогда он станет нечитаемым. Как вариант можно сделать чтобы таблица не сжималась по ширине экрана. Но тогда будет горизонтальная прокрутка на узких экранах.

Comment: @andreymal
 наверное, переносить текст вертикально, или как принято

Comment: Если вы хотите перенос текста по слогам, то [hyphens](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как в WordPress, но обычно размер ячеек подгоняется под размер содержимого. Можно попробовать добавить свойство **word-wrap** со значением **break-word** к стилям, где есть селекторы ячеек **th** и **td**.

```
   table tbody tr th, table tbody tr td {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Также можно к селектору table добавить свойство **table-layout: fixed**